# As a student, do I have a right to see my incident report as filed by campus security?

Tags: canada, human-rights

A campus peace officer made a report against me for public intoxication, but no fine or ticket was issued.  Do I have rights to access that report?

By asking for the report, could that make them decide to issue a ticket where they previously had not?

I asked directly but was told I needed to contact a lawyer. They also placed a comment in the report stating that I disobeyed them which violated my school contract and I received a warning with no information.  Without any ticket information, I am not sure how I disobeyed them. They called the police and they drove me home. I was not charged.

I realize that I'm probably making this worse for myself as I understand I got off with just a warning but the information seems falsified, as I complied with both police and peace officers. I'm gonna take it as my consequence as I understand my responsibilities but I just need some more information.

My question is, **can I have a copy of the report they filed at the time, and if so, how do I go about getting it?**

Comment: how do you know about the comment in the report?

Answer (score 2):

As a student, you are bound by the school contract you entered into as a student, and that will determine if you have a right to see a copy of the incident report filed by campus security. You need to read that contract - more commonly known as a student conduct manual or other similar title - to find out what your rights are and any actions you can take with campus security and getting your incident report, as well as any administration and student conduct committee contacts that may be helpful, possibly starting a grievance process that can lead to a resolution, any penalties you may be subject to, etc. Example: http://www.uvic.ca/services/judicial/

If it's a public school, the school's website should have a full copy of a student conduct manual; if a private school, you may need to get a copy from the administration.

Campus security is also bound by the school contract; they may or may not be correct in not releasing your incident report. That's what the school administration can tell you; ask them, rather than the security department. Look in the student conduct manual for administration and student conduct committee contacts.

If campus security told you to talk to a lawyer, they've probably dealt with such situations before and are correct in that you need a lawyer to be the go-between. You can look around for a legal aid group in your city and see if they can help you with options. *(You shouldn't ask for legal advice here.)*

> By asking for the report, could that make them decide to issue a
>   ticket where they previously had not?

It's possible, but campus security would need to be sure they have clear justification to ticket you, because they are obviously aware of repercussions (re: telling you to get a lawyer) and have lots of experience working through the processes.

The big picture is that you need to do research into your situation with the school contract you are under and any administrative, student and legal aid contacts that can help explain your options to you.